# Mailgun or Sendgrid - 501 Username used for auth is not valid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailgun

I am trying to send email with mailgun (or Sendgrid`enter code here`) and receiving this error:

`Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (501 Username used for auth is not valid email address`

My setup is as simple as it should be:

```
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
     :user_name => ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_LOGIN'], 
     :password => ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_PASSWORD'],
     :domain =>  'mydomain.co'
     :address => ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_SERVER'],
     :port => ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_PORT'],
     :authentication => :plain,
     :enable_starttls_auto => true
   }
```

Any idea?

Comment: is ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_LOGIN'] a valid email address? And are the environment variables actually working?

Comment: user_name sample (REAL data):
SENDGRID: apikey

Comment: Little unclear there but from the error message it's saying the username needs to be something in the format of an email - x@y.com.

Comment: Maybe run a manual test by telnet to the SMTP server and trying out those details. Sendgrid has a tutorial - https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/getting-started-smtp/#:~:text=%20To%20send%20SMTP%20email%20using%20Telnet%3A%20,apikey%2C%20which%20is%20YXBpa2V5%20in%20Base64.%20More%20

Answer (score 2):

It seems like some custom code logic (we use Jumpstarter for Rails) was overriding settings in production.rb file.

The most helpful thing in my case was to take a look at `rails c` (on production) and then run:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings
```

I immediately noticed that settings were not identical to those I specified. Then it was easy to find where the real issue was.

Comment: I'm wrestling with this issue also (using Jumpstart as well). Could you elaborate what you actually fixed? the ENV['MAILGUN...] settings in production.rb config.action_mailer.smtp_settings don't seem to be taking. user_name and password are empty when I run "ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings" on Heroku production.

Comment: If you plan to use Jumpstarted the way it was intended to be used maybe just use `EDITOR=vim rails credentials:edit`

If you are like me and want to keep credentials in ENV, search for `        ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = Jumpstart::Mailer.new(Jumpstart.config).settings
` and comment it (smtp_settings were overidden twice in my version of Jumpstarter)